# Is it possible to run js-test-driver tests that uses requirejs modules?

Tags: requirejs, js-test-driver

I've been trying to use [requirejs](http://requirejs.org) and [js-test-driver](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/) along side, and I can't seen to get it working.

I have a minimal configuration like this at the root :

```
server: http://localhost:9876

load:
 - src/main/resources/web/resources/vendor/requirejs/require.js

test:
 - src/test/js/*.js
```

A "src/main/js/greeter.js" file defines a silly module :

```
define(function(require) {

  myapp = {};

  myapp.Greeter = function() {
  };

  myapp.Greeter.prototype.greet = function(name) {
    return "Hello " + name + "!";
  };

  return myapp;
});
```

And I'm trying to let require load the greeter module in a "src/test/js/greeterTest.js" :

```
GreeterTest = TestCase("GreeterTest");

require.configure({ ???? });
require([ "src/main/js/greeter" ], function(myapp) {

  GreeterTest.prototype.testGreet = function() {
    var greeter = new myapp.Greeter();
     assertEquals("Hello World!", greeter.greet("World"));
    };

});
```

Whenever I run this, I get an error because myapp is not defined when creating the Greeter.

So is there a way I can configure require in this case ? I tried :

- setting the baseUrl property to something like file:///.... to give the location of the file
- using the gateway configuration to proxy the requests that requirejs might do (although I have no server running to serve the js files, so again I had to use file:///)

Is there something else I should try ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it is possible, but poorly documented  :

- js-test-driver has a ['serve'](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/wiki/ConfigurationFile) settings that lets the test server responds static files
- once served, the files are available at localhost:42442/test/xxxx (The 'test' prefix is never mentionned, except in a comment low in the doc page).

So this works :

```
server: http://localhost:9876

load:
  - src/main/resources/web/resources/vendor/requirejs/require.js

test:
  - src/test/js/*.js

serve:
  - src/main/js/*.js
```

And requirejs has to be configured like this :

```
require({
    baseUrl : "/test/src/main/js"
}, [ "greeter" ], function(myapp) {

    GreeterTest = TestCase("GreeterTest");

    GreeterTest.prototype.testGreet = function() {
        var greeter = new myapp.Greeter();
        assertEquals("Hello World!", greeter.greet("World"));
    };

});
```

Notice :

- the / before the tests
- the fact that you have to reuse the "src/main/js" part ; I guess that is linked to the fact that my jsTestDriver config is located at the same level as the "src" folder, and
  it might needs some tweaking if  placed otherwise.